# Can I use both pool and server configurations in ntp?

Tags: ntp, ntpd, conf, chrony

For a ntp demon, what happens if I have this configuation in `ntp.conf`:

```
pool 0.pool.ntp.org burst iburst minpoll 4

server europe.pool.ntp.org
```

?

How will ntp be configured?

I don't know there to be any way to query ntp for its *active* configuration - so as to know which server or pool, and which options are being used in a given moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use both pool and server configurations in your `ntp.conf`.  The server will always be included in the running configuration, and the pool members will be added and removed as determined by `ntpd`.  Note, however, that this is unlikely to be any better than simply using `pool` for both entries.  The main reason for using a configuration like the one you proposed would be to include an NTP server on your local network.

To see the list of active peers, use `ntpq -np`.  You can find more information about interpreting the output in the [NTP docs](http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/ntpq.html) (under the description of the `peers` command), or in [my blog post](https://is.gd/6IMaB0).

Note: You should **NOT** be using `burst` or `minpoll 4` with the pool.  This is considered bad form and might get you rate limited or blocked by specific servers.  Please use just `iburst` - unless you have major problems with bandwidth or buggy hardware, `ntpd` will be able to sync your system's clock just fine without `burst` or `minpoll`.

Comment: <<The main reason for using a configuration like the one you proposed would be to include an NTP server on your local network.>>

If that's the case, and the value in "pool" is `0.pool.ntp.org` while the "server" is `192.168.4.4`, then, if there's a discrepancy in the time given by the two of them, then which of them will be the one to give me the time?

Comment: @user1828163: There are always discrepancies. NTP's purpose is to work out the real time from all your sources, despite those discrepancies.  You can find out more about how it does that at http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/warp.html, specifically the parts about the Clock Filter Algorithm, Clock Select Algorithm, and Clock Cluster Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use both pool and server configurations in ntp?

Yes. Multiple, and every one will be sent NTP packets.

To ensure a given configuration, copy in your desired ntp.conf and restart the service.

Comment: And, if I want to include a NTP server on my local network, then I should use "server" instead of "pool", right?

Comment: pool is the same as server, except it resolves one name into several addresses and uses them all. You may use this on NTP servers you control, such as a ntp.example.org  with multiple AAAA records, or point it at all domain controllers via AD DS's domain name.